# Accessing an application in Salesforce which uses Ping One for their SSO

Tags: single-sign-on

Can anyone give me any pointer as to what are the steps I need to setup while accessing an external application from Salesforce, which uses Ping One service  for their SSO?

Answer (score 3):

The requirements are mentioned on the PingOne data sheet. Apart from that, the key is which technique are you actually using to authenticate with SSO. Whether it is

- Assertion contains User's salesforce.com username
- Assertion contains the Federation ID from the User object

The 2nd option is more common and you'll need to configure it in a manner similar to what's shown below.

[image]

For more details, refer to [this](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingOne/PingOne-Setup/PingOne-Configuring-Salesforce-com-to-use-the-Federated-ID-for-SSO) and [this](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityArticle?id=kA3400000008RLJCA2) link.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Could you elaborate a bit how the information flows from Salesforce to the external site and PingOne?